# Supermartingale is also a supermartingale w.r.t. right-continuous filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

I came across the following theorem in some online lecture notes. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}, P)$ be a probability space

**Thereom:** If $(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ is a supermartingale with right-continuous paths (a.s.) w.r.t. a filtration $(\mathcal{G}_t)$, then it is also a supermartingale w.r.t. the filtration $(\mathcal{G}_{t+}) = \cap_{s > t}\mathcal{G_s}$.

The proof given goes like this:

**Proof**:
For any $u$ between $s$ and $t$
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[X_t \rvert \mathcal{G}_u] \leq X_u \; \; \text{a.s.},
\end{equation}
since $(X_t)$ is a supermartingale. So for any $A \in \mathcal{G_{s+} \subset \mathcal{G_u}}$,
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[1_A  X_t] \leq \mathbb{E}[1_A X_u].
\end{equation}
Letting $u \searrow s$, $X_u \rightarrow X_s$ (by r-c) and
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{E}[1_A  X_t] \leq \mathbb{E}[1_A X_s], \tag{a}
\end{equation}
for any $A \in \mathcal{G}_{s+}$.

**My question:** How are the limit and expectation interchanged in (a)? Clearly Monotone convergence does not apply, so it must be Dominated convergence? But I can't see why. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(u_n)$ be a decreasing sequence in $(s,t)$ with limit $s$. Then
$$
\Bbb E[X_t\mid\mathcal G_{u_n}]\le X_{u_n},
$$
for each $n$. As $n\to\infty$ the right side converges to $X_s$ by right continuity. The left converges (a.s. and in $L^1$) to $\Bbb E[X_t\mid\mathcal G_{s+}]$ by the backward-martingale convergence theorem.